# Control v-list-item based on object property

Tags: vuetify.js

How can I control the active state of a v-list-item based on the property of an object? I've created a codepen for you to test. You'll see my object's have a property called **active** and some of them are marked by default as true. Which means when you first run the application they should be marked as active.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    selectionModel: [1],
    items: [
      {'name':'Sour Candy', 'active': false, color:'red'},
      {'name':'Chocolate', 'active': false, color:'green'},
      {'name':'Muffins', 'active': false, color:'blue'},
      {'name':'Cakes', 'active': true, color:'pink'},
      {'name':'Pizza', 'active': false, color:'purple'},
      {'name':'Fruit', 'active': false, color:'orange'},
      {'name':'Vegetables', 'active': true, color:'yellow'},
      {'name':'Popcorn', 'active': true, color:'indigo'}
    ]
  }),
})
```

https://codepen.io/jokermartini/pen/ExVQZgN?editors=1011

[image]

Comment: In your example, all objects with `active: true` are already selected on the list, so what is the problem then?  You are already *"controling the active state of a v-list-item based on the property of an object"*

Comment: When i start the application i have some items default to being active and i noticed it doesn't take those into account when it populates the list. then when i click the Clear button it doesn't update the icons to be gray circles instead of filled in dots

Comment: Everything works in your codepen as expected. On load, it activates 3 items and when l click `clear all` button, all dots become grey.